# Injecting Repository using Spring-Data-Solr

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I am pretty new to Spring and thought I would try spring-data-solr.

The problems seem to happen when I try to inject my TeamRepository which is an empty inteface which extends SolrCrudRepository. I've tried using annotatedConfiguration & XmlConfiguration and even both and seem to not be getting anywhere.

The stack trace i'm getting on start up is:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54211', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryTeamIndexService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public app.solr.repository.solr.TeamRepository app.solr.repository.RepositoryTeamIndexService.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
    at app.application.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public app.solr.repository.solr.TeamRepository app.solr.repository.RepositoryTeamIndexService.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:873)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.MappingSolrEntityInformation.getIdAttribute(MappingSolrEntityInformation.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository.<init>(SimpleSolrRepository.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(SolrRepositoryFactory.java:64)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 22 more
```

I've uploaded my small project to GitHub. Could someone help spot the errors?

[Project on GitHub](https://github.com/jimmyo88/spring-solr-spike)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every SolrDocument requires an `id`. You can provide this meta information by adding the `@Id` annotation on a field of your document:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class TeamDocument extends SolrDocument {

    @Id
    private String id;

    ...
}
```

The stacktrace gives you a hint (it tries to retrieve the id attribute but fails because it's not there):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.MappingSolrEntityInformation.getIdAttribute(MappingSolrEntityInformation.java:68)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe I've spent a day trying to debug this and it was that simple.